# SELinux won't let me run sshd under port 443

Tags: ssh, port, selinux

I'm running Redhat 7.7. I am trying to let the ssh-service accept connections on both Port 22 and Port 443. I have allready opened the firewalld with

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=443/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

And set

```
Port 22
Port 443
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and reloaded with

```
sudo systemctl reload sshd
```

But `sudo journalctl -u sshd` still says it can't bind to 443. What do I need to do now?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to generate a local policy, you can modify the SELinux port type of port  443 to something suitable using semanage(8).

```
semange port -l | grep ssh
ssh_port_t                     tcp      22
```

So we need to change the port type to ssh_port_t

```
semanage port -m -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 443
```

and to verify

```
semange port -l | grep ssh
ssh_port_t                     tcp      443, 22
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a selinux newbie. But here goes. I've followed this guide [SELinux - 5.6. Gathering Audit Logs In Permissive Mode](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-798c98ef37cb8a00425a048152113b7a7dc14f1b")

Switch to root as you will need root right for all the following commands

```
sudo su
```

First, you need to find which semodule blocks your port with:

```
ausearch -m avc
```

This will show you some recent errors. You need to look with which scontext the error happens. For me it was `sshd_t`

```
time-> <timestamp>
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1567419463.747:16052): proctitle=2F7573722F7362696E2F73736864002D44
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1567419463.747:16052): arch=c000003e syscall=49 success=no exit=-13 a0=3 a1=55f0f8e1cce0 a2=10 a3=7ffee40f91a8 items=0 ppid=1 pid=1339 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="sshd" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1567419463.747:16052): avc:  denied  { name_bind } for  pid=1339 comm="sshd" src=443 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:http_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket permissive=0
```

Set the module found in the scontext temporarly on permissive. Reload the sshd service and see if it works now.

```
semanage permissive -a sshd_t
systemctl reload sshd
journalctl -u sshd
```

If this works we can now create our own local semodule. In this example I call it `sshdlocal`.

Follwing command shows how the new rule will be looking like:

```
grep sshd_t /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m sshdlocal
```

In my case:

```
module sshdlocal 1.0;

require {
        type http_port_t;
        type sshd_t;
        class tcp_socket name_bind;
}

#============= sshd_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow sshd_t http_port_t:tcp_socket name_bind;
```

To actually generate and install the semodule. Do this:

```
grep sshd_t /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M sshdlocal
semodule -i sshdlocal.pp
```

You can list all semodules like this:

```
semodule -l
```

Now remove the permissive sshd_t, reload the sshd_config and check with journalctl to see if the setup is still working.

```
semanage permissive -d sshd_t
systemctl reload sshd
journalctl -u sshd
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 443
```